Writing Tikzpicture/Circuitikz in HTML
I want to display this electric circuit diagram in HTML using Latex, how can I do this?
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=.7, american voltages, voltage shift=0.5]
       \draw (0, 0) to[battery, l_={$V, r$}] (4, 0) -- (4, 3) to[R, l_=$R_{1}$] (0, 3) -- (0, 0);
       \draw (0, 1.5) to[R=$R_{2}$] (4, 1.5);
\end{circuitikz}


You can convert your TeX document to HTML using TeX4ht. It will create SVG images for all TikZ pictures.

you can also compile the .tex to a standalone .pdf, then use pdf2svg (linux) to convert to SVG. This is the workflow I use for symmetricfunctions.com

As said by michal.h21 in the comment, if you write to a file, say lalla.tex:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, american voltages, voltage shift=0.5]
       \draw (0, 0) to[battery, l_={$V, r$}] (4, 0) -- (4, 3) to[R, l_=$R_{1}$] (0, 3) -- (0, 0);
       \draw (0, 1.5) to[R=$R_{2}$] (4, 1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

and then compile it with htlatex lalla, you'll have a file lalla.html (and an accompanying lalla.svg) which, opened for example in firefox, will show:

You can find more info in https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/gurari.pdf.
